# How to make the effect of a text that is written by itself

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is a text that makes the effect that is written by itself:

A simple `<body>` with two elements to see the example:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
   <button id="write" type="button">Write!</button>
   <h1 id="text"></h1>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
 $("#write").click(function() {

        //Here is an example text to write it is a fragment from the newspaper El país on Spanish
        var text = "Llamada oculta. Al otro lado del teléfono suena una voz muy grave, fuerte, de un hombre con un inglés de ligero acento escandinavo. Soy Lars Hedegaard, creo que querías hablar conmigo. Verse no es posible. Ni se encuentra en Copenhague ni puede dar su paradero al estar bajo protección policial. Hedegaard, historiador y periodista danés de 74 años, es un reconocido y duro crítico del islam. Le grabaron en su casa, sin previo aviso según defiende, diciendo cosas como que en las familias musulmanas, las niñas eran violadas por padres, tíos y sobrinos. Por esto fue multado en 2011 con unos 700 euros.";

        var writer = ""; writer.length = 0; //Clean the string
        var maxLength = text.length;
        var count = 0;
        var speed = 5000 / maxLength; //The speed of the writing depends of the quantity of text

            var write = setInterval(function() {

                if (count > text.length) { clearInterval(write); }

                writer += text.charAt(count);
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "" + writer + "";
                count++;

            }, speed);

        $("#write").click(function() { clearInterval(write); }); //Clean the interval to avoid the execution of various intervals at the same time

    });
```

The doubt that I have is if I am using the correct way to do it, that is to say, I don't know if is better to use the loop `for`, or use `setInterval` (like in the example), and too if the code can be more simplified.

But of course, if I use `for` I will have to add a `setTimeout` inside it, and that is where I am having trouble.

**So, if any body have an other method, please let me know! Thank you!**

**Example in: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ursmnyra/1/)**

Comment: The way you implement it looks good in fact! If you really want to use any other method, you should ask it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

As it has been pointed out in the comments, you can access strings the same way as arrays, so there is no need for the `text.split()` in my original answer. The difference boils down to this, then: I would eliminate the redundant `writer` var from the code and append the chars directly to the element. Basically replace

```
writer += text.charAt(count);
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "" + writer + "";
count++;
```

with

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text[count++];
```

but in the end this comes down to coding style I think. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pbL2ub6/2/)

#### Original

Another clear way to do it would be to split the string into an array of characters. You can then keep a global counter (or simply one level up in the scope chain), and use your function inside `setInterval` to increment this counter on each iteration and append whatever character is at that index to your element - basically what you did, except with arrays to make the incrementing part a bit more straightforward.

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pbL2ub6/1/) of the proposed solution. This is without jQuery, but you get the idea.

Comment: Why split it into an array? You can access a character in a string the same way you access an element of an array.

Comment: Huh, forgot about the `[]` notation for strings in JS. I guess it's pretty much the same thing then, except with a different accessor than `charAt`. This indeed makes the splitting of the string redundant. Thanks for pointing it out!